# How to create laravel storage symbolic link for production or sub domain system?

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, console, storage

When I worked on laravel local development server `php artisan storage:link` works fine for me. But when I transfer my site to production server then I saw my public storage link was a folder. Then I delete that tried to create a link. I got an error because my app was in the root folder and tried to solve this problem.

Comment: If you want to create symbolic link in cpanel read this article https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9561/29/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-cpanel

Comment: For people looking for the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I solved this problem by another command for creating a symbolic link by terminal/cmd/shh:

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public /path/to/public/storage
```

I solved this also Using laravel web route routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Comment: in my case I had to runt this command with the full path i.e $HOME/domain.com/storage/app/public $HOME/public_html/storage . Hostgator shared hosting

Comment: how can i run this

Comment: how can we run terminal in cpanel ?

Comment: Delete public/storage folder and run php artisan storage:link again. It worked for me.

Comment: @MizanurRahmanKhan it is showing an error in command terminal. 'ln' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It works on server only when i set it in cron job to run once.

Comment: Route::get('/foo', function () {
Artisan::call('storage:link');
});

It is a perfect solution.

Comment: If you don't have server terminal access then you may use Route::get('/foo', function () { Artisan::call('storage:link'); });

Comment: Before executing your command, dont forget to check the user. The owner of the project folder and the user by which you create symlink should match. Also check for the needful folder permission. This two helped to get this working.

Comment: just apply this 2nd method in web.php(route) and see the result. work perfectly.

Comment: symlink() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: great solution, it's work on Plesk control panel for me.

Answer (score 43):

Another simple way is to run Executing `php artisan storage:link` Command Programmatically

On routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Comment: This command works fine in local but gives error in live symblink error

Comment: Life saver thank you bro works great but i had to delete the storage file existe in the public folder, then create anew symlink, thanks

Comment: `symlink(): No such file or directory`

Comment: symlink() has been disabled for security reasons

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone is looking for another flexible solution using php:

```
Route::get('/link', function () {        
   $target = '/home/public_html/storage/app/public';
   $shortcut = '/home/public_html/public/storage';
   symlink($target, $shortcut);
});
```

And make any required change to the $target variable and the $shortcut upon your files structure.

You can use the above code inside that web route or inside any other function.

Comment: very nice solution :)

Answer (score 9):

The easiest option is to run the following in a terminal

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 5):

assuming that your laravel project "public" directory and "public_html" directory are different. Or your subdomain pointer directory may be different , then use your subdomain pointer directory like "public_html" below given process.

apply command: `$ php artisan storage:link`

this command will create symlink to "public" directory to your laravel project. not inside the "public_html" . so we need to move the "storage" link to "public_html" directory. for this you can move directly. if it doesn't work then move it using command . go inside the "public" directory and run the below command according to your "public_html" directory location.

```
$ mv storage /home/yourHostinInfo/domains/domainName/public_html
```

the path might be different based on your hosting information.

Answer (score 3):

**Creating symbolic link in a web server using SSH**

In Laravel documentation, a symbolic link (symlink or soft link) from public/storage to storage/app/public should be created to make files accessible from the web.

(THIS PROCEDURE WILL CREATE SYMBOLIC LINK WITHIN THE LARAVEL PROJECT DIRECTORY)

Here are the steps on how you can create symbolic link in your Linux web server using SSH client:

**1.** Connect and login to your web server using SSH client (e.g. PUTTY).

**2.** Link storage/app/public to public/storage using the syntax.

```
ln -s target_path link_path
```

Example (in CPanel File Directory)

```
ln -s /home/cpanel_username/project_name/storage/app/public /home/cpanel_sername/project_name/public/storage
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a CPANEL web hosting its common for the domain root to be `public_html` directory which may be an issue as by default Laravel app will try to look for a folder called `public` in your project root.
To solve this open your `config/filesystems.php` file and change:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Symbolic Links
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
| `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
| the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
|
*/

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

to this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Symbolic Links
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
| `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
| the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
|
*/

'links' => [
    base_path('public_html/storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Note that we have changed the `links` array value from the default `public_path('storage')` to our custom `base_path('public_html/storage')` directory

Answer (score 3):

Just write in a php file (like symlink.php) the following code, place it in the website root folder (the folder you placed files in the public folder) and execute it by browsing in your browser to yourwebsite/symlink.php

```
<?php
symlink('/home/yourrootfolder/yourappfolder/storage/app/public', '/home/yourrootfolder/public_html/yourappfolder/storage');
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an account on Hostinger.

I had a big problem with Laravel File Manager, but now I know what was the problem :)

It`s was an issue with a link to storage.
My folder public_html had no link but the copy of storage!

1. Delete this storage or rename it if you want backup :)
2. Log in to ssh and use command pwd to get the current folder that will help you build a full path.
3. Use this command:

   ln -s <target_path> <link_path>

In my case this was like:

```
ln -s /home/u16345434/domains/website.name/storage/app/public /home/u16345434/domains/website.name/public_html/storage
```

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue creating a symlink to a folder located under `subdomain`, tried everything for almost 3 hours, and no luck. My case was as follow:

1. The uploads folder is located under subdomain: `images.example.com`.
2. I upload images using the root document: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/`
3. I want to create a symlink in that root document.

**Finally, I tried this solution and it works as expected:**

`ln -s /home/customer/www/images.example.com/public_html/uploads /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/uploads`

*Note: I used `PuTTY` to create that symlink*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works for me in the production server

```
 Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    $targetFolder = base_path().'/storage/app/public';
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve the problem instead of `ln -s path/to/target path/to/public/storage` just type:

`ln -srv ~/path/to/target ~/path/to/public/storage`

but first create the folder storage in public.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and tried all methods in this question but not working for me!

so, this is the way I solved it:

edit `config/filesystems.php` file:

before:

```php
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been set up for each driver as an example of the required values.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],
```

after:

```php
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been set up for each driver as an example of the required values.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public', // NEW LINE
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public', // CHANGED LINE
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],
```

ONE important point:
it works only if you use `Storage::url()` to create file URLs!

Answer (score 0):

In laravel if you want to create symbolic storage link to root folder, there already storage named folder exists. you can try it

```
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    $targetFolder = base_path().'/storage/app/public';
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/symstorage';
    symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder);
 });
```

and use {{ asset('symstorage/images/' . $demo->photo) }} for accessing file in production server

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is access the server through SSH, navigate to the root path where it is your laravel project, for example:

```
cd /path/to/your/domain/public_html
```

then navigate to the `public` directory(laravel project) and delete the `storage` directory if you have uploaded it...

and go back to the `public_html` and run the command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

that will get the job done...