# Upload Image not saved at directory on server Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I deploy my website, and I have a bug on my upload image, this image can't saved at directory

my directory is in `public_html` on folder named *files*.

on localhost its not having a problem but after I deploy this, I have it.

my Controller on my localhost (not have a problem like this)

```
public function store6(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [


    ]);

    if ($request->hasfile('image'))           
    {   
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);  
        $data = $name;  
    }

    $user = new pemeliharaan;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
    $user->pertanyaan =json_encode($request->except
    (['_token','name','alat_id','status','catatan','image']));
    $user->catatan = $request->catatan;
    $user->image=$data;
    $user->status = $request->status;


    $user->save();
  // dd($user);

    return redirect('user/show6')->with('success', 'Data Telah Terinput');    
}
```

this image "name" saved on DB but this file not saved, cant someone corrects my code?

Comment: Did you check files folder whether it's there or not?

Comment: i checked this folder , and i found it , but i try to upload , this image cannot saved , , i think this problem on this .$file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);

Comment: Is your `files` folder in the directory `public_html` or `public_html/public`?

Comment: on public_html/files/image.png

Comment: i removed folder public because following tutorial on deploy this laravel web

Answer (score 0):

If your `files` folder is in the root path of your project and not in the `public` folder of your Laravel installation, you would need to use the [`base_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-base-path) helper instead of the `public_path` helper to move your file.

```
$file->move(base_path('files'), $name);
```

Comment: didnt work sir ,, how if we removed this base_path or public_path ?

Comment: So, usually in a project, you'll create a symlink in `public/storage` to the `storage/app/public` directory. This way things don't get mixed up. How's your `public` folder named now? Did you just rename it to `public_html`? How's your directory structure?

Comment: i dont have public folder now , i remove it . because i following tutorial to removed this , so in my folder is public_html / files / image.png

Comment: this files like css,bower_component its in the public_html /css/blablabla.css

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
       $file = $request->file('image');
       $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $imagePath = $file->storeAs('/files/' . $name . '', 'public');
}
```

and don't forget to run `php artisan storage:link` if not linked.

Comment: in Cpanel you've to create Symbolic Link
`ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public /path/to/public/storage`

Comment: Another simple way is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418359/2850383

Comment: how i can run this ? this Symbolic link

Comment: Try the simple way I've suggested

Comment: i run  this storage linked but didnt solved this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193398/discussion-between-kashyap-merai-and-adhik-mulat).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
public function store6(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
           //your validation code
    ]);

    if ($request->image != ''){   
        $path = 'files/';
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($path, $name);  
        $data = $name;  
    }

    $user = new pemeliharaan;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
    $user->pertanyaan =json_encode($request->except
    (['_token','name','alat_id','status','catatan','image']));
    $user->catatan = $request->catatan;
    $user->image=$data;
    $user->status = $request->status;


    $user->save();
  // dd($user);

    return redirect('user/show6')->with('success', 'Data Telah Terinput');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to **run**  this **Symbolic link** first

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Try to upload now.

if not work,

then check any **symbolic storage folder** present in **public folder**

If Yes, then **delete** it (Take **backup** if required before deleting it).

Now **run again**

```
 php artisan storage:link
```

Now try again to upload.

Its worked for me.