# Laravel 9: Storage link not downloading the Image with 404 error on Cpanel shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am working on a laravel 9 (php 8) project and I have done with the image uploading path. Image is uploading perfectly in storage folder and the url generate by `asset('storage/' . $user->profile_pic)` is working perfectly on localserver. After uploading my project on
Cpanel server, I have again linked the storage folder with public/storage with following command.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Images are uploading perfectly on Capnel which I have verified from public/storage folder. Now I am again generating the Image url with `asset('storage/' . $user->profile_pic)` but this time server his showing

> page not found error with 404

here is my filesystem.php file

```
    return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been set up for each driver as an example of the required values.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

Controller function to save base64Image and get the url of saved image for testing.

```
public function test(Request $request)
    {
      
        // decode the base64 image
        $base64File = request('profile_pic');
        $fileData = base64_decode($base64File);

        $name = 'users_profile/' . Str::random(15) . '.png';
        
        Storage::put('public/' . $name, $fileData);
        // update the user's profile_pic
        echo asset('storage/' . $name);

    }
```

Cpanel .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:{}
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL={myurl}

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE={my Databse}
DB_USERNAME={my user name}
DB_PASSWORD={my password}

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Firstly try to delete the generate folder in public folder and re-generate it

Comment: Yes I have tried with that deleted and re-generating the public folder

Comment: did you upload the photo to your server in the storage/app/public folder?

Comment: Probably you need to play a little bit with the htaccess file since you're on a shared hosting and laravel does require a little change on a shared hosting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create laravel storage symbolic link for production or sub domain system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825889/how-to-create-laravel-storage-symbolic-link-for-production-or-sub-domain-system)

Comment: Yes I have deployed my project on shared hosting.

Comment: This is link of URL that is used for generating/ downloading the image

https://unified.mlbranch.com/public/storage/users_profile/eY91GCjDhweZm4P.png

Comment: @OMiShah I have tried with the links that you have shared but it did not work for me ?

Comment: Is this project located in a sub folder? @QaziAmmar

Comment: no I have made a separate sub domain outside the public_html folder

Comment: On Cpanel I am able to solve this by changing the folder permission to 777

Answer (score -2):

update your code

```
asset('storage/' . $user->profile_pic)
```

to

```
asset('/storage/' . $user->profile_pic);
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference!!